# Perforce :Deleted file in client space : Unable to recover the file from server

Tags: perforce

I deleted a file in client work space.
rm *.py.
when i do a p4 sync -f , it is only refreshing the file how can i get back the file from server.
Thanks,
Rashmi

Answer (score 4):

p4 sync -f is the right command.

Some things to check:

Are you syncing the right client?
Does the client view include the file?

Comment: client view includes the entire directory,where the file is present.When i use the same server and port.No i am able to view the same in windows client.Somehow i am not able to get the file into linux view.

Comment: Can you post the output from the p4 sync -f command?  Also, you'll want to use separate clients/workspaces from each computer.

Comment: I hit this as well, it might be a client bug. I was busy so i didn't spend the time to try to reproduce it. I had 1 client spec, and use root and alt root to use it in windows and linux. Did a sync in windows, then did a force sync in linux, it didn't do anything. I'm pretty sure I did a checkout, then revert then sync -f worked. There are probably other ways, but like I said, I didn't have the time.

Answer (score 1):

One reason this can happen is that you had already checked out those files. For example, if you checked out the whole directory and then delete it, p4 sync woudn't work as you expect.
Run p4 revert and then p4 sync -f ... should work.